# SolidJS: "computations created outside a `createRoot` or `render` will never be disposed" messages in the console log

Tags: warnings, solid-js

When working on a SolidJS project you might start seeing the following warning message in your JS console:

`` computations created outside a  `createRoot`  or `render` will never be disposed ``

There are some information available on this in SolidJS' Github repository issues. But after reading them I was still not quite sure what this was all about and whether my code was really doing something wrong.

I managed to track down where it came from and find a fix for it based on the documentation. So I'm providing the explanation and the solution for those Googling this warning message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In essence this is a warning about a possibility of a memory leak due to a reactive computation being created without the proper context which would dispose of it when no longer needed.

A proper context is created a couple of different ways. Here are the ones I know about:

- By using the `render` function.
- By using the `createRoot` function. Under the hood `render` uses this.
- By using the `createContext` function.

The first is by far the most common way, because each app has at least one `render` function call to get the whole show started.

### So what makes the code go "out of context"?

Probably the most common way is via async calls. The context creation with its dependency tree happens only when the synchronous portion of the code finishes running. This includes all the `export default` function in your modules and the main app function.

But code that runs at a later time because of a `setTimeout` or by being in an `async` function will be outside of this context and any reactive computations created will not be tracked and might stick around without being garbage collected.

### An example

Let's say you have a data input screen and have a `Save` button on it that makes an API call to your server to save the data. And you want to provide a feedback to the user whether the operation succeeded or not, with a nice HTML formatted message.

```js
[msg,setMsg] = createSignal(<></>)

async function saveForm(){
  ...
  setMsg(<p>Saving your data.<i>Please stand by...</i></p>)
  const result=await callApi('updateUser',formData)
  if(result.ok){
    setMsg(<p>Your changes were <b>successfully</b> saved!</p> )
  } else {
    setMsg(<p>There was a problem saving your data! <br>Error: </p><pre>{result.error}</pre> )
  }
} 

...
  <div>
    ...
    <button onClick={saveForm} >Save</button>
    {msg()}
  </div>
```

This will produce the above mentioned warning when the API call returns an error, but not the other times. Why?

The reason for this is that SolidJS considers the code inserts inside JSX to be reactive, ie: need to be watched and re-evaluated. So inserting the error message from the API call creates a reactive computation.

### The solution

I found the solution at the very end of the SolidJS doc. It's a special JSX modifier: `/*@once*/`

It can be used at the beginning of a curly brace expression and it tells the SolidJS compiler to explicitly not to make this a reactive expression. In other words: it will evaluated once and only once when the DOM nodes are created from the JSX.

In the above example here's how to use it:

`setMsg(<p>There was a problem saving your data! <br>Error: </p><pre>{`**`/*@once*/`** `result.error}</pre> )`

After this there will be no more warning messages :)

---

In my case, I had an input and when that input changed I re-created an SVG drawing. Because the SVG creation was an expensive operation, I added a debounce in the `createEffect` function which ran when the input changed. `debounce` is a technique to defer the processing until the input stops changing for at least X amount of time. It involved running the SVG generation code inside the `setTimeout` function, thus being outside of the main context. Using the `/*@once*/` modifier everywhere where I inserted an expression in the generated JSX has fixed the problem.

Comment: Great answer. In my case, I replaced the `signal containing the JSX` with a `signal containing the data the JSX depended on`. ...in retrospect, that's what I should've been doing in the first place. SolidJS saving me from myself.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: He is rendering elements under an async function. Rendering uses computations internally which can not be tracked directly under an async function. Creating computation under an async function is same as creating computation outside a tracking scope because the computation is executed in the event loop, after the syncronous code is run that is what makes it go out of the tracking scope. Problem is solid can not establish ownership tree so can not dispose the child computations when they are run outside a tracking scope. App will leak memory because more and more computations will be created with each state update.

Solution: Not rendering elements under an async function or providing proper owner using the runWithOwner function.

The error "Computations created outside a root" is emitted when you execute a computation outside a tracking scope.

What is a computation? Any form of effect that can subscribe to a signal, including the ones that are created via `createComputation`, `createEffect`, `createRenderEffect`, `createComponent` and `createMemo` functions. Solid components are also effects.

What is a tracking scope? Tracking scope is a JavaScript scope that has access to an owner. If `getOwner` function returns a value, you are inside a tracking scope. There are several ways to create a tracking scope but the most basic one is `createRoot`, others like `render` or `createContext` calls it internally.

Why do we need a tracking scope? For memory management. A tracking scope tracks an effect's dependencies. Think of a component, a component can create a DOM element, and it have child components that can create other DOM elements. It is not only the components but even regular effects can host other effects inside its body.

If an effect listens for a signal, it will re-run. When they re-run they will repeat whatever they do. If it is creating a component, it will create new component. Effect hosting other effects that host other effects, may consume large amount of resource. If their consumption is not managed, it will get out of hand quickly.

When an effect is created under a tracking scope, Solid assigns an owner for for it, and builds a tree that shows who owns whom. Whenever an owner goes out of scope any computation owned by that owner gets disposed.

Tracking scope tracks internal resources, resources created by SolidJS itself. For external resources like socket connection you need release them manually via `onCleanup` hooks.

The effect may have access to a signal or not is irrelevant. This dependency tracking exist outside a signal. Try running any effect that has no signal access, you will get the error all the same:

```js
import { createEffect, createSignal } from 'solid-js';
createEffect(() => console.log('Hello World'));
```

You will receive this error if you execute an effect inside an async function even if the async function lives under a tracking scope. Why? Because Solid run synchronously. It runs in cycles. Effects subscribe to a signal when they react its value and unsubscribe once they are called back. So, everything is build up and tear down in each update cycle. When the async function runs, the owner of the previous cycle will be discarded long ago. So, the effect that lives inside an async function will be detached from the dependency tree and go rogue. But solution is simple: Providing an new owner by wrapping the effect with `runWithOwner` function:

```js
runWithOwner(outerOwner, () => {
  createEffect(() => {
    console.log('Hello World');
  });
})
```

For other cases where you do not have a root scope, it is best to use `render` or `createRoot` functions.

Here you are creating elements and storing them inside a signal and rendering them inside the div element.

```js
async function saveForm(){
  setMsg(<p>Saving your data.<i>Please stand by...</i></p>)
  const result=await callApi('updateUser',formData)
  if(result.ok){
    setMsg(<p>Your changes were <b>successfully</b> saved!</p> )
  } else {
    setMsg(<p>There was a problem saving your data! <br>Error: </p><pre>{result.error}</pre> )
  }
}
```

You can get rid of the async function, or do not render the element under the async function. Updating state inside an async function is OK but renderin is not.

Now it is time to explain how `@once` pragma solves the problem inside the accepted answer:

First and foremost, you are creating a component inside the callback function by invoking the `setMsg`.

The `@once` pragma marks a prop value as static value.

Take this component:

```js
<Comp count={count()} />
```

NORMALLY, the count prop is compiled to a getter function that returns the value:

```js
_$insert(_el$3, _$createComponent(Comp, {
  get count() {
    return count();
  }
}));
```

This is to preserve the reactivity when passing values from parent to child.

When `@once` added, the prop's value will be treat as a static value:

```js
_$insert(_el$3, _$createComponent(Comp, {
  count: count()
}));
```

Remember we said components are effects. When `@once` used, Solid treats the children as static values, not as components. In other words Solid does not see any effect inside the async function, but a function invocation that returns a static value:

```js
<pre>{/*@once*/ result.error}</pre>
```

By the way, the example code that is used inside the accepted answer is not an idiomatic Solid component. It is best not to mix UI and state like that.

Comment: You mention that it is not an idiomatic Solid component. How would an idiomatic component look like for this example? Since I am also struggling a bit with this. I suppose it is about using JSX inside the signal?

Comment: @Dima The answer explains the root cause of the problem in detail. In short, he is missing the root computation, solid complains because there is no way to track and dispose child computations that are not needed anymore. Solution is rendering the application under `render` function or `createRoot` function. His solution is not idiomatic for several reasons. That is not how you make an api call, or display messages. He is mixing state and UI, creating an element and storing it inside a signal. It is not wrong but ugly and convoluted. It is best to use resourceAPI to make the api call and

Comment: use conditionals for rendering the UI elements. If I had to store an element inside a signal, I would use a memo for performance and clarity. It is hard to offer an optimal solution because there is no way to know his purpose by looking at his code. But if you have difficulty to render async data, you can check this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/74590574/7134134 If you give more detail about your problem, I can be more specific. One last thing, rendering elements under an async function causes this problem, I have a detailed answer for that too, you can check my answers.