# How to use Ref in Solid.js?

Tags: solid-js

So i am learning and start play around with Solid.js, and I want to know how do we handle ref in solid.js like useRef in react.

I check the doc I try something like this:

```js
      let navigationOuterRef: HTMLDivElement
      let navigationRef: HTMLUListElement
    
     const MenuNavbar = (props: {layoutDatas: LayoutNavigation[]}) => {
        
       const [priorityItems, setPriorityItems] = createSignal<LayoutNavigation[]>(props.layoutDatas);
      
      //....
    
      return (
        <div ref={navigationOuterRef} class="....">
          <ul ref={navigationRef} class="...">
            <For each={priorityItems()}>
              {(labelName) => (
                <li class="flex items-center cursor-pointer">
                  {labelName.label}
                </li>
              )}
            </For>
          </ul>
        //...
```

it work... but I got the warning message like

> computations created outside a `createRoot` or `render` will never be disposed

So I think the issue is the fact i create the ref outside the component so without a proper context it cannot be disposed if unmounted, but if i moved the ref declaration in the component I have this error in TS

> Variable 'navigationOuterRef' is used before being assigned.

so what I am doing wrong and what is the right approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, components requires you to run them under a proper owner, that is either `render` function, or a root created via `createRoot` function or another component. This is needed to build an ownership tree, a tree that show who owns whom so that when a component is disposed, its resources will be cleaned up. So, the warning message is nothing to do with refs, but about components created outside a reactive context.

Other than that refs are handles to underlying DOM nodes. They come in two flavors: variables and functions.

Variable forms requires you to use `onMount` hooks because when components are loaded, ref will be undefined, only after render phase completes they point to the actual DOM element.

```js
let ref;

console.log(ref); // undefined

onMount(() => console.log(ref)); // div

<div ref={ref} />
```

Why they are not available immediately is because Solid runs the assignment operation while building the DOM tree.

```js
<div ref={el => ref=el} />
```

Variable form is basically a syntax sugar for the function form.

Since ref is not available initially, the correct type of the ref element is:

```js
let navigationOuterRef: HTMLDivElement | undefined;
```

If you do not put `undefined`, you will have the type error:

```
Variable 'X' is used before being assigned
```

Function form receives the DOM element as soon as the DOM node becomes available:

```js
function handleRef(ref: HTMLDivElement) {
  console.log(ref); // div
}

<div ref={handleRef} />
```

Compiled code invokes the ref function while creating the DOM tree.

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#ref

Comment: thanks for your detail answer, so what you re saying, is the fact I have declare ref at the right place outside the component, and the warning message is coming from another issue that i have to find out ?

Comment: As I explained ref is not available until internal assignment runs, so the correct type for your ref should be `HTMLDivElement | undefined` Updated the answer.

Comment: Damn, you are right i was mislead it was a TS error >.> but as you mention it has nothing to do with ref for the warning, it' s coming from a function i call in the createEffect that cause issue so i am trying to figure this out... :)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76030785/7134134